# IPN Subscription only taking credit card

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've setup a IPN subscription system that works quite well, but there is 1 issue. If they have PayPal balance they can't use it, and it will only let them use their credit card? Is there any way to get around this? Maybe using PayPal API? instead of IPN...?

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

A credit card or other external funding source is required for subscriptions and billing agreements